# Laravel 5.2 link to route error

Tags: laravel

my `web.php`

```
 Route::get('/', ['as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'PagesController@home']);

 Route::group(['prefix'=>'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('register',[ 'as'=>'get_register',
        'uses'=>'Auth\RegisterController@getRegister'       ]);
    Route::post('register',[ 'as'=>'post_register',
        'uses'=>'Auth\RegisterController@postRegister'      ]); 
});
```

my `nav.blade.php`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CodeHub</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Log In</a></li>
              <li>{!! link_to_route('get_register', 'Register') !!}</li> //To link my register button with route
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

my `register.php`

```
@extends('layouts.masters.main')

@section('page-content')

    <div class="container">

      @includes('layouts.partials.nav')

      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

my `Register Controller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**It was supposed to display Sign up form when I go to this url http://localhost/test/public/auth/register but I am getting the following error.**

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 333: Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::getRegister() does not exist
```

Can anyone help thanks. Its hard for me to make out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I assume you're not using the inbuilt auth scaffold? `make:auth`

Comment: `'uses'=>'Auth\RegisterController@getRegister'` where is getRegister() method?

Comment: It comes from the `use RegistersUsers;` trait.

Comment: make:auth worked I tried doing the old version manual way.

Answer (score 1):

Error is pretty clear: there is no `getRegister()` method in `Auth\RegisterController`.

If you want to use Laravel auth scaffolding, remove your routes and add `Auth::routes();` instead.

Comment: This method is in the `RegistersUsers` trait.

Comment: @TheFallen so OP will need to override it in `RegisterController` if he wants to call it. Laravel itself is calling `register()` method by default.